# print linked list in assembly

Tags: assembly, linked-list, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to print a linked list, so far it prints just the first node, I can't find the right way to get the data from the next node. this is what I have so far and the the mistake is in the print loop but  I don't know how it will look on the stack to fix it

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data

sundaystr byte "today sunday  ", 0
mondaystr byte "monday   ",0
tuesdaystr byte "tuesday  ",0

sunday dword sundaystr
dword monday
dword 0

monday dword mondaystr
dword tuesday
dword sunday

tuesday dword tuesdaystr
dword 0
dword monday

.code
main PROC
push sunday

printlist PROC

push edx
push esi
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov esi, [ebp+12]
print:
mov edx, esi
call writestring
add esi , 4
mov edx, esi
call writestring

;mov eax , [esi]
;cmp eax , 0
;je done
;jmp print


done:
pop ebp
pop esi
pop edx

printlist endp
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, C-like code of this would be

```
struct List
{
    const char* name;
    List* first;
    List* second;
};

void PrintList(List* list)
{
    WriteString(list->name);
    if (list->first != NULL)
    {
        WriteString(list->first);
        PrintList(list->first);
    }

    if (list->second != NULL)
    {
        WriteString(list->first);
        PrintList(list->first);
    }
}
```

A rewritten x86 asm code would look like this:

```
    ; init function frame
    ; esi = List* list
    mov edx, esi         ; load list to edx (points to name)
    call writestring     ; print name

    add esi, 4           ; add 4 to esi, now points to first
    mov edx, esi         ; edx points to first
    cmp edx, 0           ; if (first != NULL)
    je second

    call writestring     ; print first
    call printlist       ; print content of first list
                     ; note that esi gets pushed/popped in the function
second:
    ; do the same again for the List* second
    add esi, 4
    mov edx, esi
    cmp edx, 0
    je end

    call writestring
    call printlist

end:
    ; clear function frame
```

It's very probable this answer is not entirely correct/what you want, but I guess you'd be able to move somewhere from there...

PS. I recommend you to use comments extensively. It's really not easy to read what you're doing. And it will help you yourself see the code clearer.